# WordPress - custom categories partly showing in menus

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a very strange issue. I have a few custom posts types created along with these I have categories added to these.
There is a number of categories and sub-categories. There is no issue with displaying any of them (through View link) and there is no issue adding posts to these.
However, when I go to menus I can only see a few sub-categories and sometimes none.
I have extended max_vars to 10000 and nothing happened.

[image]
[image]

I have tried to:

- Add posts to all of the categories.
- Create new navigation
- Extend php max_vars
- Updating everything
- Switching theme
- Removing and adding sub category

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function advertisement() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Advertisements', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Advertisement', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Advertisement Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Advertisement Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Advertisement Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Advertisement:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Advertisements', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Advertisements', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Advertisement Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set Advertisement image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove Advertisement image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as Advertisement image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Advertisements list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Advertisements list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Advertisements list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Advertisement', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Advertisement Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'ads' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-post',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'advertisement', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'advertisement', 0 );

//Categories
function classifieds_sub_categories() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Categories Ad', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Category Ad', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Category Ad', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Category Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Category', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'classifieds_categories', array( 'advertisement' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'classifieds_sub_categories', 0 );
```

Comment: I would recommend to share snippet of your code. Because you are showing what a user would see in the GUI. Your problem could be related to Wordpress SDK code or in your PHP code.

Comment: PHP code? Code of what? Custom post type? There is no other code related to this...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the following code to see if it works.
 'capability_type' => 'post',

Comment: No change, the issue persists.